# Shortcut key for switching into desktop

Tags: shortcut-keys, games

In Windows there is a shortcut key to minimize a game. 
It's like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>
to join taskmanager or sign out of your account. Is that possible in Ubuntu?

I tried <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>. It works but not if I've opened a game.

Comment: What kind of game are you running?

Answer (score 1):

Try <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Spacebar</kbd> and then <kbd>n</kbd>.